# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: kotlin, testing, automation, appium, appium-android

I am currently working something on automation testing of some small mobile application and first time trying to implement Appium.

I have a trouble when running the test with the following error - ***org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.***

Tried many things, but no success. I have installed the Appium server locally version 2.1.3 which is the latest at the moment. I also have Appium Inspector installed where I get the resource Ids for the elements to access later in the tests.

Here is the test example I am trying

```
package com.example.myfood_kotlin.appiumtests.foodjokes.favorites

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType
import org.junit.Test
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
import java.net.URL
import java.time.Duration

class FavoritesRecipesAppiumTest{

    @Test
    fun testRecyclerViewIsDisplayed() {
        // my-ip-address should be replaced with the appropriate ip - see from appium command terminal
        val appiumServerUrl = URL("http://(my-ip-address):4723") // NOTE: when using appium 2.* version the default remote path is / (not /wd/hub)

        val capabilities = DesiredCapabilities()
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "selendroid");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android")
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.example.myfood_kotlin")
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.example.myfood_kotlin.ui.MainActivity")
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2")
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true)
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true)

        val driver = AndroidDriver(appiumServerUrl, capabilities)

//        Thread.sleep(4000)

//        val wait = WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
//        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("com.example.myfood_kotlin:id/search_button")))

        // Click on the favorites button (assuming it's an element with resource id)
        val fragment = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.myfood_kotlin:id/favoriteRecipesFragment"))
        fragment.click()

        // Verify that the RecyclerView is displayed (assuming it's an element with resource id)
//        val view = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.myfood_kotlin:id/favoriteRecipesRecyclerView"))
//        view.isDisplayed

//        Thread.sleep(4000)

        driver.quit()
    }
}
```

I have tried also implicit waiting, thread sleeping, trying different selectors but nothing helped me.
Here in the inspector we can see the resource id of the element I am trying to access.

[Picture of Appium Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/824rR.png)

NOTE: I am using a virtual device created as part of the Device Manager in Android Studio, and in debugging mode the AndroidDriver is initializing okay, when it comes to the part to get the element *(noted as fragment in the example above)* it crushes.

Thank you in advance :))

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you did not put all path of the element,

Could you try this?

```
val fragment = driver.findElement(By.id("favoriteRecipesFragment"))
```

Comment: Didn't had any success with this one. It still throws the error NoSuchElementException...